# How to compare two @ character in clojure

Tags: clojure

Please, how can I write this in clojure? I have an `@` character and I want to compare it to `"@"`.

eg `(= @ "@")`

gives error `(ClassCastException java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.concurrent.Future  clojure.core/deref-future (core.clj:2206))`

Comment: So is it that you're using the character '@' as a symbol which is being bound to some value and then you want to ensure that symbol has the value '@'? Regardless, the reason for the error is that @ is a reader macro for the deref function which is used to essentially await the value of a future, in your code you're attempting to deref a string, which isn't possible. Your question needs a bit more context I would say.

Comment: don’t forget deref accesses atoms etc as well! it’s deserving of its special case, common code would be more verbose and harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

Yoy can quote your @ using \@ for Clojure to interpret it as a character literal. By default @ is a reader macro for a deref form to make many other things in clojure less verbose. Anyway:

```
(= \@ \@)

true
```

If you want to check that the first character of a string is a @ then:

```
(= \@ (first "@"))

true
```

The following only works in Clojurescript as it doesn't have a character type and just uses strings of length one.

```
(= \@ "@")

true ;; in cljs only
```

Comment: The second example (the surprising one) is _not_ true for me (in clj 1.10).

Comment: `(= \@ "@")` returns false for me

Comment: as for `(= \@ "@"): seems like you were testing it with clojurescript, and since it doesn't have character class, just the string with length = 1, equality check resolves to true, no surprise. In clojure for jvm it predictably yields to false.

Comment: caught out by using Replete on the phone to check some things and didn't think it throuigh. Thanks all have updated the answer for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

There's an inherent conflict in this comparison, in that `"@"` is a string sequence of characters and `\@` is an individual character.  If you wanted to confirm that the string consisted of a single character which matched the `\@` symbol, something like the following would be work:

```
(let [s "@"]
  (and (= \@ (first s)) (= (count s) 1)))
```

However, if you want to detect if the string contains *any* `\@` characters or if it just *started* with an `\@` character, that requires different code.  This is the problem with comparing strings and characters -- it's not inherently obvious what you need from the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you get the error? The [reader](https://clojure.org/reference/reader#_deref) translates your example into ...

```
(= (deref "@"))
```

[The `deref` function](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L2298) tests whether the argument is deref-able (implementing `IDeref`). If not, it treats the argument as a future. It isn't, so it throws the confusing exception. This behaviour is a defect, albeit a minor one.

By the way, `(= x)` returns `true` for any `x`, if it returns at all.

[Tim Clemons' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56347975/1562315) shows what you can do about this.